# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when trying to use/load Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common not found even when is included in references

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have a project that references the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common assembly like this:

[image]

But when I try to run the project I amd getting and error on this line

[image]

The error that I am getting is:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' en
>   Sitefinity.DAO.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ni una de sus dependencias. El
>   sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

**What have I tried:**

- I have removed and added the reference again
- I have checked that the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` is in the same folder as the `Sitefinity.DAO.dll`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You can use Fuslog and see any binding errors to make sure it is not one of the dependencies that is actually missing

Comment: Fuslog is showing nothing, not an single row or message, this is an asmx service does that work with Fuslog ?

Comment: Have you configured FusLog to write Binding failures to disk?

Comment: @Kzrystof if you create an answer with how to launch and configure fuslog I will upvote and accept it, many thanks